# How to use Custom User Model for authentication Djoser - Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, custom-authentication

Its not clear from the documentation, but I want to achieve 2 things:

1. Use my custom user model which inherits from models.Model.
2. It has a password field which stores password using sha1. I need to use model with that password field for authentication.

Since, the tables were used as it is in the project earlier need to use those only.

I need to use any token based authentication.

Can someone please point to the correct direction. I read django-rest-framework documentation, it pointed out to use Djoser for custom user model. But I'm unable to figure this out. How.

Comment: Is your custom user model extended from Django's [Abstract UserModel](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)?

Answer (score 3):

creating a custom user Model inheriting from models.Model is a very bad idea instead use AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser.

Having created a custom, you have set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`  to your User model in `settings.py`.

Then just import the Djoser User Registration Serializer And override it.

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserRegistrationSerializer

class UserRegistrationSerializer(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ('city', 'state', 'email', 'name', 'last_name', 'account_address', 'password', )
```

You can also override other things in the serializer like create and update methods in case if you want to customize it.

And in settings.py tell djoser to use it like so

```
DJOSER = {
    ...
    'SERIALIZERS': {
         'user_create': 'yourapp.serializer.UserRegistrationSerializer'
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not create custom user inheriting from `models.Model` instead use `AbstractUser`

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) are relevant docs.

If you follow the Django docs Djoser should work without a problem.

Djoser and many other auth related packages use functionality provided by `AbstractUser`

Answer (score 0):

You can use JWT token authentication. http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/. If you set AUTH_USER_MODEL in your setting file to your custom user model then it will validate user. Or you can write custom methods for authentication.